# What's the easiest way to add custom filename autocomplete behavior for a command?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I want to add some rudimentary filename completion for programs like `ghc`, `ghci` (Haskell compilers), `lyx` (typesetting program), namely that hitting `[tab]` after one of the above should offer autocomplete suggestions for files ending in ".hs" or ".lyx".

What's the easiest way to do this in zsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
compdef '_files -g "*.hs *.lyx"' ghc ghci lyx
```

See `man zshcompsys | less -p '^\s*compdef \['` and generally `man zshcompsys`.

Comment: fantastic, thanks so much!! (The question was badly worded; I actually meant `compdef '_files -g "*.hs"' ghc ghci;
compdef '_files -g "*.lyx"' lyx`)